# What is a clear and precise way to describe a plan to build a system based on a particular COTS product?

Tags: phrase-requests, sentence

I am writing an experience report about a recent technology consulting engagement. The intended audience is not necessarily familiar with consulting, the bidding process, or even particularly technical. In the summary I wrote the following statement:

> While working at [X Inc.], I co-authored a successful proposal to develop the system based on a business process management system called [Foo].

Several reviewers of the report were confused by that sentence. Foo is a commercial off-the-shelf (COTS) product business process management system that can be customized to a particular application. Some were unsure whether Foo was a requirement specified in the request for proposals or if it was something my team at X Inc. proposed. (It was something we proposed). Others were unclear what exactly it means to develop a system based on Foo. (We customize Foo to the particular application). What can you suggest as a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *"based on"* is slightly clunky phrasing here - *"using"* seems more natural. Paraphrasing to remove the irrelevant verbiage:

> *We wrote a successful proposal to develop the system **using** [Foo].*

To emphasise that *the decision to use [Foo]* originated with the proposers, write "**by using**".

Comment: After years of Microsoft ads, I am conditioned to interpret [Foo] as the tool you used to write the proposal, e.g. *We outlined how to diagram the structure using Visio.* This would particularly be the case where the audience is not familiar with the product name.

Comment: @choster: If you were to just read *my* rephrasing, I suppose you could justify that interpretation. But OP's full version explicitly points out that [Foo] is *business process management system*. I omitted that from my version because it didn't directly relate to the **based on/using/by using** distinction I was making, just as I omitted stuff at the beginning of his sentence. By *"irrelevant verbiage"* I meant *those words that don't impact directly on OP's question* - which is about how to convey that OP and his colleagues **chose** [Foo] as the development tool.

Answer (score 2):

I accept the point that it is not clear whether *Foo* is a requirement or your technical approach, which could be addressed by rewording. If the audience is going to be confused by the concept of *based on Foo*, however, I think more explicit language and additional background will be required.

> [Y Corp.], a Singapore-based manufacturer of widgets and widget accessories, was in need of a new business process management system. While working at [X Inc.], I co-authored a successful proposal to use a customized version of [Foo] for that system, rather than building a new one from scratch.